# Constantly random flying object/rectangle WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I am creating simple game in C# WPF just to learn more about language. My goal is to create game similar to space invaders. I am creating enemy, which i want to fly random from point to point. However, it flies to first randomed point and then just keep repeating doing the same move ( including teleporting to start point, which is not my point as u can guess ) Can anybody help my figure out what can i change/add here ? Here is method which creates and moves that object. I dont think any more code is needed here ( i mean from the whole game ).

```
        public void CreateEnemy()
    {
        Random randomEnemy = new Random();
        Rectangle enemy = new Rectangle();
        var Urii = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Modele/ufoRed.png");
        enemy.Width = 30;
        enemy.Height = 30;
        ImageBrush enemyImg = new ImageBrush();
        enemyImg.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(Urii);
        enemy.Fill = enemyImg;
        myCanvas.Children.Add(enemy);

        enemy.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, 400d);
        enemy.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, 0d);

        Storyboard enemyAnimate = new Storyboard();
        DoubleAnimation enemyAnimation;

        int topRandom = randomEnemy.Next(50, 300);
        int leftRandom = randomEnemy.Next(0, 500);
        //up and down
        enemyAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(topRandom, new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 5)));
        enemyAnimation.AutoReverse = false;
        Storyboard.SetTarget(enemyAnimation, enemy);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(enemyAnimation, new PropertyPath("(Canvas.Top)"));
        enemyAnimate.Children.Add(enemyAnimation);
        // left and right
        enemyAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(leftRandom, new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 5)));
        enemyAnimation.AutoReverse = false;
        Storyboard.SetTarget(enemyAnimation, enemy);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(enemyAnimation, new PropertyPath("(Canvas.Left)"));
        enemyAnimate.Children.Add(enemyAnimation);
        enemyAnimation.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
        enemyAnimate.Begin();
    }
```

Greetings, 
kim0z

Comment: dont create a new random without a seed, and dont create a new random with each creation.. have 1 random in in your app

Comment: And don't create a new enemy Rectangle on each call, but reuse one that you create once.

Comment: WPF really isn't the best option for games - if you want to learn the language I'd build a desktop app, it's more the right fit for the tool. If you want to create a game you want to use a game engine.